# "Pending changes" filter in rider

Tags: rider

I often use "pending changes filter" in Visual Studio to filter changed files in solution explorer, which is helpfull in large solutions.
https://www.visualstudiotips.co.uk/tip/pending-changes-filter/

Now i use rider instead VS.
Does such thing exist in rider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible right now. Feel free to vote for the next issue:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-16273

There is a separate tool window `Commit` instead. If you enable `Group by Directory` option it should work for you almost in the same was as a filter in the solution explorer.